# Template.body.helpers returns no value

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

As my ROOT_URL differs in Dev and Prod environments I am rtying to use the `Meteor.settings` functionality to set my `href` values correctly.

Because links are used all over the application, it seemed a natural candidate for a helper on the body template. It is defined like so:

```
  Template.body.helpers({
     rootURL: Meteor.settings.public.root_url
  })
```

and in the template it is used like so:

```
<li class="{{guessesActive}}">
    <a href="{{rootURL}}guesses" class="waves-effect waves-light">Guesses
        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

But the value of `Meteor.settings.public.root_url` is not appended to the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add as a registered helper instead of appending to the body. `Template.registerHelper('rootURL', function() {...});` Then return the appropriate value. Meteor docs have more on `registerHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I misunderstood the `body` template. I thought it was meant to be accessible for all. It runs out this is not the case. It is meant to allow using helpers directly in the `<body>` tag.

To set global helpers, define a global variable called `Helpers` and assign it an object with the functions and variables you want accessible.

As explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28837834/763962